# Check via cookie to see if a user allready seen a div

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have some content (alertbox) and I need visitors to see (closed) it once. So when they have seen (closed) it, it shouldn't come up anymore.

I think this can be done via cookies (php of javacript)?

My php knolegde is basic/avarage but my javascript is pretty much zero.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a cookie with JavaScript and on the next page reload check it with JavaScript again.
Here is a basic example to demonstrate how it works:

Say, in your html code we have this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clickMe()"> Close</a>
<div id="popup"> Popup </div>
```

JavaScript snippet at the end of the file will be like this:

```
<script>
function clickMe(){
    document.cookie='popupSeen=true; expires=Thu, 1 Jan 2099 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}
    ~document.cookie.indexOf('popupSeen=true') ? document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none" : false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we have to check if the user has already seen the Div. That's why we have to check if the cookie is set. If the cookie is set we don't display the div. If it is not set we display the div and set the cookie.

```
If($_COOKIE["seen_div"] != 1){
     setcookie("seen_div",1,time()+(3600*24));
     //show div
}
```

The time is in seconds. That means that 3600 is one hour multiplied by 24 and it's a day. The cookie ist deleted after a day. Of course you can change the time if you want to.

Comment: I understand your point so I tried this:`<script>

If($_COOKIE["yw_cookie_notice_seen"] != 1){
     setcookie("yw_cookie_notice_seen",1,time()+(3600*24));
     //show div
 print('<div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove" uk-alert>The message...</div>');
}

</script>` but nothing is showing. Thanks

Comment: Woops its PHP ofcourse but when I change to <script> with php quotes nothing changes :(

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the // like this:<?php If($_COOKIE["yw_cookie_notice_seen"] != 1){ setcookie("yw_cookie_notice_seen",1,time()+(3600*24));echo '<div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-remove" uk-alert>The message...</div>'; } ?>